# How to correctly position prev and next buttons at the middle of flexbox carousel?

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox

I am trying to add prev and next at the vertical middle and the both ends. It seems the only way to place `prev` at the middle is to give `margin-top:50px` if the container div height is 100px. But container height could vary so makes no sense to hard code it. Also, since there is a horizontal scroll I cant place `next` at the other end towards right.

```css
::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}

.scrolling-wrapper-flexbox {
  display: flex;
  display:flex-inline;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  overflow-x: auto;
  -ms-overflow-style: none;
    ::ng-deep  .card {
    flex: 0 0 auto;
    margin-right: 3px;
  }

}
  ::ng-deep .card {
    border-radius: 10px;

  border: 2px solid grey;
  width: 150px;
  height: 100%;
  background: white;
  text-align: center;
    padding-top: 3px;
}

 .scrolling-wrapper-flexbox {
  height: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  width:50%;
  flex: 0 0 50%;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
  ::-webkit-scrollbar {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  
  <div > 
<div class="scrolling-wrapper-flexbox" #widgetsContent>
       <span style="background-color:red" class="card">prev</span>

  <div class="card">
    
      <img src="https://img.icons8.com/material/4ac144/256/camera.png"  alt="Smiley face"  width="90" height="90"  >
  </div>
  <div class="card">
      <img src="https://www.freeiconspng.com/uploads/flat-blue-home-icon-4.png"  alt="Smiley face"  width="90" height="90"  >
  </div>
  <div class="card">
      <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/e/e0/WPVG_icon_2016.svg/1024px-WPVG_icon_2016.svg.png"  alt="Smiley face"  width="90" height="90"  >
  </div>
  <div class="card">
      <img src="https://img.icons8.com/material/4ac144/256/camera.png"  alt="Smiley face"  width="90" height="90"  >
  </div>
  <div class="card">
      <img src="https://www.freeiconspng.com/uploads/flat-blue-home-icon-4.png"  alt="Smiley face"  width="90" height="90"  >
  </div>
  <div class="card">
      <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/e/e0/WPVG_icon_2016.svg/1024px-WPVG_icon_2016.svg.png"  alt="Smiley face"  width="90" height="90"  >
  </div>
  <div class="card">
      <img src="https://img.icons8.com/material/4ac144/256/camera.png"  alt="Smiley face"  width="90" height="90"  >
  </div>
  <div class="card">
      <img src="https://www.freeiconspng.com/uploads/flat-blue-home-icon-4.png"  alt="Smiley face"  width="90" height="90"  >
  </div>
  <div class="card">
      <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/e/e0/WPVG_icon_2016.svg/1024px-WPVG_icon_2016.svg.png"  alt="Smiley face"  width="90" height="90"  >
  </div>

</div>
        <div class="next">Next</div>

  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Please keep in mind that I am not using bootstrap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add one more flex container and add prev button, content and next button and give align-items center to make it vertically center.

```css
::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}

.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  align-items:center;
}

.scrolling-wrapper-flexbox {
  display: flex;
  display:flex-inline;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  overflow-x: auto;
  -ms-overflow-style: none;
    ::ng-deep  .card {
    flex: 0 0 auto;
    margin-right: 3px;
  }

}
  ::ng-deep .card {
    border-radius: 10px;

  border: 2px solid grey;
  width: 150px;
  height: 100%;
  background: white;
  text-align: center;
    padding-top: 3px;
}

 .scrolling-wrapper-flexbox {
  height: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  width:50%;
  flex: 0 0 50%;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
  ::-webkit-scrollbar {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  
  <div class="flex-container">
  <div class="card">prev</div>
<div class="scrolling-wrapper-flexbox" #widgetsContent>
       

  <div class="card">
    
      <img src="https://img.icons8.com/material/4ac144/256/camera.png"  alt="Smiley face"  width="90" height="90"  >
  </div>
  <div class="card">
      <img src="https://www.freeiconspng.com/uploads/flat-blue-home-icon-4.png"  alt="Smiley face"  width="90" height="90"  >
  </div>
  <div class="card">
      <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/e/e0/WPVG_icon_2016.svg/1024px-WPVG_icon_2016.svg.png"  alt="Smiley face"  width="90" height="90"  >
  </div>
  <div class="card">
      <img src="https://img.icons8.com/material/4ac144/256/camera.png"  alt="Smiley face"  width="90" height="90"  >
  </div>
  <div class="card">
      <img src="https://www.freeiconspng.com/uploads/flat-blue-home-icon-4.png"  alt="Smiley face"  width="90" height="90"  >
  </div>
  <div class="card">
      <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/e/e0/WPVG_icon_2016.svg/1024px-WPVG_icon_2016.svg.png"  alt="Smiley face"  width="90" height="90"  >
  </div>
  <div class="card">
      <img src="https://img.icons8.com/material/4ac144/256/camera.png"  alt="Smiley face"  width="90" height="90"  >
  </div>
  <div class="card">
      <img src="https://www.freeiconspng.com/uploads/flat-blue-home-icon-4.png"  alt="Smiley face"  width="90" height="90"  >
  </div>
  <div class="card">
      <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/e/e0/WPVG_icon_2016.svg/1024px-WPVG_icon_2016.svg.png"  alt="Smiley face"  width="90" height="90"  >
  </div>

</div>
<div class="next">Next</div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yep! Exactly what I was looking for. Many thanks! :)